# Object reference not set to an instance of an object #100

Tags: c#, object, reference, null, instance

I know people have asked this before, but it would appear that their solution doesn't work for me or I'm doing something wrong.

```
public class Sprite
{
    private Game m_game;
    private SpriteBatch m_spriteBatch;
    private string m_filename;
    private Texture2D m_texture;

    public Sprite(Game game, SpriteBatch spriteBatch, GraphicsDevice graphicsDevice)
    {
        m_game = game;
        m_spriteBatch = spriteBatch;
        m_texture = new Texture2D(graphicsDevice, graphicsDevice.Viewport.Width, graphicsDevice.Viewport.Height);
    }

    public void LoadSprite(string filename)
    {
        m_texture = m_game.Content.Load<Texture2D>(filename);
    }
}
```

The error is generated at LoadSprite when I pass "tree" as the filename.
m_texture isn't null because (tried to) initialise it in the constructor.
The same call to Content.Load is used in the main loop fine but I want to move that into the Sprite class.

```
treeTexture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("tree");
```

This works fine in the main loop so it shows that the "tree" file exists.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Is m_game or m_game.Content null?

Comment: Well your IDE should easily provide you which object is NULL. We don't know...

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)

Comment: It shouldn't be since I passed it when I created the new Sprite:
Sprite tree4 = new Sprite(game, spriteBatch, GraphicsDevice);

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with things like "C#". On [so], we use tags for that.

Comment: Sorry about that John, it's my first post, I'll make sure not to in future.
It would appear m_game IS null... How come it's not being passed to the class properly?

Comment: Post some code of how you are calling the sprite class. You are probably calling the constructor with NULL values.

Comment: Sprite tree4 = new Sprite(game, spriteBatch, GraphicsDevice);

game was a previously defined Game type.
I think the problem is that I want to point to the ContentManager (Content) of my main class but that's not the proper way to do it.

Actually, just fixed the problem by setting "game" in the main class to equal "this"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

m_game or m_game.Content is probably null.

Comment: m_game was null because "game" that was passed to it in the call was null. I had to put: game = this; in the constructor of the main class.